# шифратор и дешифратор шифра Виженера

Tags: java

Помогите,пожалуйста,необходимо написать программу шифратора и дешифратора с ключом с помощью квадрата Виженера. Я не понимаю как это сделать((

Answer (score 5):

Люблю этим заниматься, по этому, так уж и быть, написал примерчик:

```
final class Vigenener {

    private final int bias,
            letters;

    public Vigenener(final int bias, final int letters) {
        this.bias = bias;
        this.letters = letters;
    }

    public String encrypt(final String text, final String key) {
        String encrypt = "";
        final int keyLen = key.length();
        for (int i = 0, len = text.length(); i < len; i++) {
            encrypt += (char) (((text.charAt(i) + key.charAt(i % keyLen) - 2 * this.bias) % this.letters) + this.bias);
        }
        return encrypt;
    }

    public String decrypt(final String cipher, final String key) {
        String decrypt = "";
        final int keyLen = key.length();
        for (int i = 0, len = cipher.length(); i < len; i++) {
            decrypt += (char) (((cipher.charAt(i) - key.charAt(i % keyLen) + this.letters) % this.letters) + this.bias);
        }
        return decrypt;
    }
}
```

А теперь разберемся, что происходит:
Все конечно же зависит от алфавита, которым будем использовать и какой текст будем шифровать - ключ которым будем шифровать также зависит от алфавита, за исключением некоторых (мы не можем использовать русские ключи, при шифре английского алфавита, но зато можем использовать английские ключи при шифровании русской строки).

Каждая первая буква алфавита, есть смещение.
Я приведу примеры только 2х-алфавитов русский и английский.

**Русский:**

```
final String key = "ру";
final Vigenener v = new Vigenener(1072, 33);
String enc = v.encrypt("русский", key);
System.out.println(enc); // ѐеагъыщ
String dec = v.decrypt(enc, key);
System.out.println(dec); // русский
```

В конструкторе класса `Vigenener` первым аргументом `1072` - это смещение по первому символу алфавита, вторым аргументом `33` передается количество букв алфавита.
Дальше следует метод шифрования `encrypt` - первым аргументом передается текст который будем шифровать, а вторым аргументом, передается ключ, которым будем шифровать - этот ключ понадобится для расшифровки ранее зашифрованного текста.

**Английский:**

```
final String key = "en";
Vigenener v = new Vigenener(97, 26);
final String enc = v.encrypt("english", key);
System.out.println(enc); // iakymfl
String dec = v.decrypt(enc, key);
System.out.println(dec); // english
```

Также все аналогично, что описано выше.

Как узнать нужное смещение, просто приведите первую букву алфавита к целочисленному типу в одинарных кавычках `'` - так-как в `Java` двойные `"` кавычки = строка, а строку нельзя приводить к целочисленному типу, а символьный тип можно:

**Английский (количество букв = 26):**

```
System.out.println((int)'a'); // 97
```

**Русский (количество букв = 33):**

```
System.out.println((int)'а'); // 1072
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку в строках
`System.out.println(enc); // iakymfl
System.out.println(dec); // english
System.out.println((int)'a'); // 97`

Comment: @Иван, а куда вы это вставляете? Это должно быть в методе `main`, вы хоть немного в `java` соображаете или методом тыка пытаетесь запустить алгоритм? - так не пойдет, учите  `java`, а потом задавайте вопросы. Я и так за вас написал целый алгоритм, остается только просто копировать и вставить.

Comment: @Иван, выберите вопрос в качестве решения, рядом с вопросом есть галочка, нажмите на нее.